# Multiple output files for hadoop2 streaming jobs

Tags: java, python, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to split output of the job by date (`key=date`, `value=big_json`).

In hadoop1 I had a special Java class, inherited from `MultipleTextOutputFormat`.
As far as I know, this is deprecated in hadoop2.

[The documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/LazyOutputFormat.html) [points out](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html), that

> Use in conjuction with
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs to recreate the
>   behaviour of org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat
>   (etc) of the old Hadoop API.

But I don't really understand how to use it in my script. What params should I use?

> hadoop jar /usr/local/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.4.4.jar -D mapred.job.name=split-parsed-logs -D mapred.reduce.tasks=140 -D mapred.task.timeout=10000000 -mapper python -m timestamp-and-json -reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer -input /tmp/parsed_logs -output /tmp/splitted_logs -file /home/user/app.mod -cmdenv PYTHONPATH=app.mod -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs

Comment: Try look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100621/multipletextoutputformat-alternative-in-new-api

Comment: Didn't found how to use it in streaming though, I guess i'll have to write java class for that job.