# Hadoop multiple outputs with speculative execution

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, multipleoutputs, speculative-execution

I have a task which writes avro output in multiple directories organized by few fields of the input records.

```
For example : 
Process records of countries across years 
and write in a directory structure of country/year 
eg:
outputs/usa/2015/outputs_usa_2015.avro 
outputs/uk/2014/outputs_uk_2014.avro
```

```
AvroMultipleOutputs multipleOutputs=new AvroMultipleOutputs(context);
....
....
     multipleOutputs.write("output", avroKey, NullWritable.get(), 
            OUTPUT_DIR + "/" + record.getCountry() + "/" + record.getYear() + "/outputs_" +record.getCountry()+"_"+ record.getYear());
```

What output commiter would the below code use to write the output.Is it not safe to be used with speculative execution?
 With speculative execution this causes(may cause) org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException

In this post
[Hadoop Reducer: How can I output to multiple directories using speculative execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824215/hadoop-reducer-how-can-i-output-to-multiple-directories-using-speculative-execu)
It is suggested to use a custom output committer

The below code from hadoop AvroMultipleOutputs does not state any problem with speculative execution

```
 private synchronized RecordWriter getRecordWriter(TaskAttemptContext taskContext,
          String baseFileName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    writer =
                ((OutputFormat) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(taskContext.getOutputFormatClass(),
                    taskContext.getConfiguration())).getRecordWriter(taskContext);
...
}
```

Neither does the write method document any issues if baseoutput path is outside the job directory

```
public void write(String namedOutput, Object key, Object value, String baseOutputPath)
```

Is there a real issue with AvroMultipleOutputs (an other outputs) with speculative execution when writing outside the job directory?
If,then how do i override AvroMultipleOutputs to have it's own output committer.I can't see any outputformat inside AvroMultipleOutputs whose output committer it uses

Comment: Did you write your own implementation? I have the same question.

Comment: When you say "With speculative execution this causes(may cause) org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException", have you seen this documented anywhere, or are you speaking from experience. We are seeing the same behavior but have not found any explicit references to disable speculative execution when using multiple outputs.

Comment: Yes it is documented. There is a warning about it  here http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

Answer (score 1):

`AvroMultipleOutputs` will use the `OutputFormat` which you have registered to Job configurations while adding named output e.g using `addNamedOutput` API from `AvroMultipleOutputs` (e.g. `AvroKeyValueOutputFormat`).

With `AvroMultipleOutputs`, you might not be able to use speculative task execution feature. Even overriding  it either would not help or would not be simple.

Instead you should write your own `OutputFormat` (most probably extending one of the available Avro output formats e.g. `AvroKeyValueOutputFormat`), and override/implement its `getRecordWriter` API, where it would return one `RecordWriter` instance say `MainRecordWriter` (just for reference).

This `MainRecordWriter`would maintain a map of `RecordWriter` (e.g. `AvroKeyValueRecordWriter`) instances. Each of these `RecordWriter` instances would belong to one of the output file. In `write` API of `MainRecordWriter`, you would get the actual `RecordWriter` instance from the map (based on the record you are going to write), and write the record using this record writer. So `MainRecordWriter` would be just working as a wrapper over multiple `RecordWriter` instances.

For some similar implementation, you might like to study the code of [MultiStorage](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.pig/piggybank/0.12.0-cdh5.2.1/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.java) class from `piggybank` library.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a named output to `AvroMultipleOutputs`, it will call either `AvroKeyOutputFormat.getRecordWriter()` or `AvroKeyValueOutputFormat.getRecordWriter()`, which call `AvroOutputFormatBase.getAvroFileOutputStream()`, whose content is

```
protected OutputStream getAvroFileOutputStream(TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {
  Path path = new Path(((FileOutputCommitter)getOutputCommitter(context)).getWorkPath(),
    getUniqueFile(context,context.getConfiguration().get("avro.mo.config.namedOutput","part"),org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroOutputFormat.EXT));
  return path.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration()).create(path);
}
```

And `AvroOutputFormatBase` extends `FileOutputFormat` (the `getOutputCommitter()` in the above method is in fact a call to  `FileOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter()`.  Hence, `AvroMultipleOutputs` should have the same constraints as `MultipleOutputs`.